# How to disable notifications for a specific board?

Tags: trello

Some times I don’t want to get notified from some boards, but I didn't find how disable/enable a specific board’s notifications.

Is this possible? And if yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Trello guide](https://www.trello.com/guide):

> You get a notification when you are added to a card, you were invited
>   to a board or organization, you were mentioned in a comment, or when
>   somebody does an action on a card you are on. Notifications are
>   represented on the Trello site with a red icon and number in the top
>   right corner.
>
> You can also subscribe to any visible card. When subscribed, you'll
>   get notifications about that card. To subscribe, open the card and
>   click the subscribe button in the sidebar.

Most notifications are global, only by subscribing (or not) to cards can you "filter" notifications.
The closest you could achieve is too (un)subscribe to all cards on a specific board.